# Setting up multiple IPs with same port?

Tags: linux, debian

I have multiple IPs I have attached to my server, is it possible to have a port say 7777 work for both IPs to separate services?

Or something like forwarding something like 10.0.0.1:7777 to 10.0.0.1? For direct connect?

I've tried searching google but I just get stuff about opening ports and mapping???

Comment: Are they on separate NICs? Are you running `iptables`? By 'separate services' do you mean 'services' as in a server like mysql running on port 3306 on your server? Or 'services' as in ea. IP address is bound to a different NIC and or network path?

Answer (score 2):

Clarify if you have a dual-NIC configuration in terms of hardware, or just two addresses to a single adapter in your soft network config?

You could try this with `iptables` - Examples that make sense: [IPTables Rules by Example/](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/)

```
> iptables -i eth1 -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
> iptables -i eth0 -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
```

Using a Forwarding chain is a bit more complex, but you could tweak this in how you needed to configure going to/from the same/different IP and/or Ports:

```
> iptables -i eth1 -A INPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.1.1 --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
> iptables -i eth0 -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:7778
> iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 7778 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 7778 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: When making a new iptables file do I also have to include rules for port 80 and such or does the new rule just push to the existing rules?

Answer (score 1):

Most daemons have some options like *listen* or *bind* to setup the address to listen.